# Move RDS Aurora Instance from private to public subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, subnet

I currently have the typical setup of an RDS cluster with 1 instance running in a *private* subnet. I am migrating our application out of AWS and into Heroku (while leaving the DB as is), but I need to be able to connect to the DB from the Heroku dynos.

What I can't figure out is how to move the DB out of the private subnet and into a public one.

[The AWS docs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-move-to-private-subnet/) have instructions for moving from public to private, and I thought I could just follow them for the opposite direction too. But the process involves standing up a new secondary in the desired subnet using Multi-AZ configuration and a failover. But when I go to Modify my instance, there is no option for configuring Multi-AZ:

[image: No Multi-AZ]

It seems like Aurora instances in particular do not support Multi-AZ? ["Multi-AZ DB clusters are in preview for RDS for MySQL and RDS for PostgreSQL"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.MultiAZ.html) Leaving me somewhat stuck.

*Edit* I did just see this message elsewhere: "You have no Aurora Replicas in your DB cluster." which might be why Multi-AZ is not available. But I'm not seeing any options to spin up a replica anywhere.

Again my goal is to get my Aurora DB into a public subnet (or otherwise make it accessible from the internet, but not through an SSH tunnel)

Answer (score 0):

The Availability Zone options are in the "Availability & durability" section above "Connectivity" FYI

I just had your same issue but with a Postgres DB, though I have the [option to change its "Subnet group" in the Connectivity section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaLm8.png), which you don't have it seems, but it only appears for me if the DB is NOT currently multi-AZ. AWS will prevent you from moving the DB between subnet groups* in the same VPC, but you can just move the DB to a subnet group in a different VPC and then move it back to the subnet group that you actually want it in (configured with the appropriate public subnets).

*You can create subnet groups in the RDS service, left side menu.